# ClipByValue error when deploying to ML Engine

Tags: tensorflow, keras, google-cloud-ml

When trying to deploy a keras model to ML Engine I get

```
$ gcloud ml-engine versions create v2 --model=plantDisease01 --origin=gs://${BUCKET_NAME}/
plantDisease01 --runtime-version=1.4                                                       
Creating version (this might take a few minutes)......failed.                              ERROR: (gcloud.ml-engine.versions.create) Bad model detected with error:  "Failed to load model: Loading servable: {name: default version: 1} failed: Not found: Op type not registere
d 'ClipByValue' in binary running on localhost. Make sure the Op and Kernel are registered
in the binary running in this process.\n\n (Error code: 0)"
FAIL
```

my storage looks like

```
$ gsutil ls gs://keras-class-191806/plantDisease01/export                      [23:29:38]
gs://keras-class-191806/plantDisease01/export/
gs://keras-class-191806/plantDisease01/export/saved_model.pb
```

I built the protocol buffer version using this approach https://stackoverflow.com/a/44232441/630752

Answer (score 1):

`ClipByValue` was [introduced in TensorFlow 1.8](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/commits/700a6698e634391cf96a314f378a8de973b49995/tensorflow/compiler/tf2xla/kernels/clip_by_value_op.cc). You can either [register](https://www.tensorflow.org/extend/adding_an_op#op_registration) the op yourself or just change the `--runtime-version` flag's value to 1.8.